# I am trying to print a div content to pdf using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am trying to print a DIV content in pdf file.  Onclick it opens a new page and the content and the printer window pop ups, but the content is not as the page
This is the javascript code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/estilos-impresion.css" media="print" />
<script language="Javascript">
    $(document).on('click','#imprimir' ,function() {
    printDiv('impri')
    });
    function imprSelec(checklist) {
            var printContents = document.getElementById(checklist).innerHTML;
            var document_html = window.open('_blank');
            //var contenidoOriginal= document.body.innerHTML;
             document_html.document.write( "<html><head><title></title>" );
             document_html.document.write( "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css\" type=\"text/css\"/>" );
             document_html.document.write( "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css\" type=\"text/css\"/>" );
             document_html.document.write( "</head><body>" );
             document_html.document.write('</center></body></html>');
             document_html.document.write('<html><head><style>#in {display:none}</style><body   onload="window.print()"></body></html>');
             document_html.document.write( printContents );
             document_html.document.write( "</body></html>" );
             setTimeout(function () {
                   document_html.print();
               }, 500)
}
```

and this is the result. Page layout when trying to print in pdf is different
[image]

How can I print in pdf with javascript a div content with same forma?

Comment: Can you use `@Media print` to solve your problem?